# React mock Graphql subscription

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, graphql, jestjs, graphql-subscriptions

I have a react project, which I am testing using Jest.  I am trying to mock a call to AWS graphql and in particular, a subscribe. Here is the code I am trying to mock

```
await API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation(subscriptions.addedProduct))
    .subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        this.setState({ products: [...this.state.products, response.value.data.addedProduct] })
      }
    });
```

I usually mock using spyOn with something like this...

```
const mockProducts = jest.spyOn(API, 'graphql').mockImplementation(async () =>
  Promise.resolve(mockResponse)
);
```

but would get the error

> TypeError: _awsAmplify.API.graphql(...).subscribe is not a function

Has anyone got an example of mocking a subscribe in a similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock the return value of `API.graphql` as an `Observable` that come from reactive programming. Then, you can use `.subscribe` method. Below example, I use the `of` operator of `rxjs` to create an `Observable`.

E.g.

`main.jsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { API } from './api';

export class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [],
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    await API.graphql('graphqlOperation(subscriptions.addedProduct)').subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        this.setState({ products: [...this.state.products, response.value.data.addedProduct] });
      },
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>my component</div>;
  }
}
```

`main.test.js`:

```js
import { MyComponent } from './main';
import { API } from './api';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('61454572', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const mockResponse = { value: { data: { addedProduct: 'fake product' } } };
    const graphqlSpy = jest.spyOn(API, 'graphql').mockImplementation(() => {
      return of(mockResponse);
    });
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent></MyComponent>);
    expect(wrapper.state('products')).toEqual(['fake product']);
    expect(graphqlSpy).toBeCalledWith('graphqlOperation(subscriptions.addedProduct)');
    graphqlSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61454572/main.test.jsx (11.328s)
  61454572
    ✓ should pass (12ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   88.24 |      100 |   83.33 |   86.67 |                   
 api.js   |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 5-6               
 main.jsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.119s
```